# crear contador para blog, contar cuantos post tiene una categoria en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Estoy intentando crear un contador de post por categoria. Es decir, la categoría x tiene tantos post.

Para ello estoy tratando de usar Eloquent. Casi todos los post pertenecen a una cetegoría y hay un post que pertenece a otra... adjunto captura

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo esta función que es la que debería de contar y agrupar por categorias. Esta en el `Modelo` de `blog` y `blog` está relacionado con `blog_category` mediante `blog_category_id`

```
/**
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
    */
    public function getPostCounterAttribute()
    {
        return $this->blogCategory()->orderBy('blog_category')->count();
    }
```

en la vista tengo esto para sacar los datos de las categorias y los post que contienen cada una:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
     <li><a href="{{ url('blogs/'.$category->name) }}">{{ trans('web.blog_category_'.$category->name) }}</a><span>{{$category->postCounter}}</span></li>
@endforeach
```

pero siempre me muestra 1en todas las categorias y no es así. Se que no lo estoy haciendo bien.

Como podría solucionar esto¿??

Gracias y un saludo

**update**

he hecho my query en phpmyadmin y este es el resultado:

```
SELECT blog_category.name, count(blogs.id) 
 FROM blogs 
INNER join blog_category 
 on blogs.blog_category_id = blog_category.id 
 GROUP by (blog_category.name)
```

en mi modelo de blog, como han dicho las respuestas de abajo intento eso:

```
public function getPostCounterAttribute()
{
    //return $this->blogCategory()->orderBy('blog_category')->count();
    
    return Blog::withCount('blog_category')->get();
}
```

resultado:

No aparecen los totales en la vista, no se conoce ninguna propiedad que asocie al contador

**update 2**

resultado de `$category` para una categoría del foreach

```
{"id":10,"name":"recipes","created_at":"2021-02-18 13:07:25","updated_at":"2021-02-25 10:37:38","custom_fields":[],"has_media":false,"media":[]}

$category->postCounter -> no muestra nada
```

contenido de `$categories`

```
[{"id":10,"name":"recipes","created_at":"2021-02-18 13:07:25","updated_at":"2021-02-25 10:37:38","custom_fields":[],"has_media":false,"media":[]},
```

**update 3**

mi relacion dentro de BLOG

```
public function blogCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\BlogCategory::class, 'blog_category_id', 'id');
    }
```

**update 4**

en el controller

```
$postCategories = BlogCategory::withCount('blogs')->get();
        
        return view('web.blog')
            ->with('data', $data)
            ->with('posts', $posts)
            ->with('categories', $categories)
            ->with('popular', $this->popularPostToday())
            ->with('postCategories', $postCategories[0]);
```

Comment: Desconozco Laravel, pero si tiene un método `orderBy()`, seguramente también tendrá un `groupBy()` para agrupar por categoría y el conteo sea efectivo.

Comment: Laravel ya tiene una cláusula para [contar los modelos relacionados](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models), co el cual no tendrías que crear tu propio método. De lo que muestras ahí, no se entiende por qué haciendo un loop sobre categorías intentas usar el accesor que según dice está en el modelo `Blog`

Comment: @Triby así es. He conseguido crear la consulta de manera manual, pero necesito hacerla con eloquent, que es el ORM de laravel

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ gracias por tu respuesta pero lo que pretendo es desde el mismo modelo, hacer eso, como se haría¿??Por otro lado, utilizo el accesor para coger la propiedad del modelo que trae los datos y los recorro en un loop para mostrar al lado de mi categoría los post que contiene, cada una. Quizás no es la lógica, pero lo pensé así. Seguro que se puede hacer mejor, por eso estoy aquí

Comment: @scorpions porque simplemente no utilizar `withcount()`? Para que cuente cuantos post hay en una categoria

Comment: @JuanRivera no lo he usado nuca, no sabía que existía. estoy probando con eso, pero me devuelve que el metodo witCount() no está definido. Estoy trabajando en laravel 5.8

Comment: @scorpions el metodo esta desde Laravel 5.3, podrias hacer lo siguiente: `Category::withCount('post')->get();` asi en tu vista solo llamas `$category->post` y ya tienes la cantidad de post que hay en cada categoria. Aqui la [documentacion](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: @scorpions te dare una respuesta para que lo implementes

Comment: @JuanRivera gracias por la ayuda, he actualizado mi pregunta con las modificaciones que se han hecho y mi consulta real en phpmyadmin para que se vea lo que necesito y aparte de que si esa categoría no tiene post que ponga un 0

Comment: ¿Que tienes en `$categories` cuando haces `@foreach($categories as $category)` y luego `$category->postCounter`? ¿Podrías mostrar la consulta con la que asignas el valor a la variable `$categories`?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ en el update 2 he puesto todo lo que me solicitas

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ si correcto, perdona se me olvidó. ya está puesto en el update 4 y eso lo paso a la vista pero al recorrerlo en la vista, siempre aparece 0

Comment: en update 2, pone contenido de $categories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para poder contar los post que existen en una categoria se puede utilizar `withCount` que basicamente

> Cuenta el numero de modelos relacionados para una relacion

Para poder utilizarlo es necesario hacer la modelacion(`hasMany->hasOne, etc`), en tu caso la relacion que muestras es de "uno a muchos" (blog_category puede tener muchos blogs), asi que en tu modelo "Blog" debe haber la relacion `hasMany`

```
class BlogCateogry extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'blog_category';

    public function blogs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Blog::class, 'blog_category_id');
    }
```

Asi en tu controlador ahora llamas al funcion que nombre:

```
# Controlador
$categories = BlogCateogry::withCount('blogs')->get()

# Vista
@foreach($categories as $category)
     <li><a href="{{ url('blogs/'.$category->name) }}">{{ trans('web.blog_category_'.$category->name) }}</a><span>{{$category->blogs_count}}</span></li>
@endforeach
```

**EDIT:** Utilizar `withCount()` en un modelo

Normalmente este se utiliza en el controlador porque ahi asignas el metodo y depues lo obtienes en tu vista, ahora para ponerlo en el modelo hay que indicarle el `id` del registro que se quiere contar porque sino obtendria de todos los registros. Para implementarlo, agregamos lo siguiente en el modelo "BlogCategory":

```
public function getPostCounterAttribute()
{
    return $this->where('id', $this->id)->withCount('blogs')->value('blogs_count');
}
```

O utilizar el metodo `loadCount`, para poder contar los post que existen en una categoria, que segun documentacion significa

> Cuenta el numero de modelos relacionados para una relacion

Por lo cual el `getPostCounterAttribute` seria asi:

```
public function getPostCounterAttribute()
{
    return $this->loadCount('blogs')->blogs_count();
}
```

Cabe resaltar que este metodo se implemento desde **Laravel 6**, asi que tendrias que utilizar la funcion anterior, lo pongo solo como informacion extra

Y en la vista lo obtenemos asi: `$category->postCounter`:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
     <li><a href="{{ url('blogs/'.$category->name) }}">{{ trans('web.blog_category_'.$category->name) }}</a><span>{{$category->postCounter}}</span></li>
@endforeach
```

**Referencia**

- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models
- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-a-single-row-column-from-a-table
- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#deferred-count-loading

Comment: Aunque induje las relaciones de acuerdo a lo que pones, si no coincide edita tu pregunta poniendo la relacion que haces y de donde obtienes `$categories`

Comment: @JuanRivera Agradezco toda tu ayuda. Lo del controlador lo podríamos hacer en el modelo del blog¿??

Comment: @scorpions si, ahora lo edito para que veas

Comment: estoy probando como me has dicho en el controller y blogs_count no viaja en $category viaja directamente de la variable que se le pase del controller a la vista, había que hacer otro for-each?

Comment: he entendido tu código, lo he aplicado y es justo lo que quería... pero siempre en el loop me muestra 4 en los totales. He impreso el contenido de mi variable que paso a la vista, y ahí si vienen correctos. Sabrías como puedo solucionar eso¿?. De nuevo gracias por todo

Comment: @scorpions me surgio algo asi que te podria ayudar mañana, por lo que me dijistes la variable viene con el dato correcto, entonces en el loop tambien deberia de ser correcto tal vez estes llamandolo mal

Comment: sin problema. Ya continuo yo. muchas gracias por todo!!!

Comment: @scorpions ya agrege lo pidistes "desde el modelo utilizar `withCount`. Lo otro del error, tendrias que editar tu pregunta para ver como obtienes el registro